# Why is the address of http.Request.URL.Host same for 2 different http.Request structures?

Tags: pointers, go, struct

This code is a self-contained example from a large code base to try to replicate a bug. When this program is run, the address of both `&request.URL.Host` and `&request1.URL.Host` is same. Why? From my understanding, these are 2 different structures so `URL.Host` should not have the same address.

```
package main

import (
        "crypto/tls"
        "fmt"
        "net/http"
        "net/url"
)

func main() {
        hostname := "www.google.com"
        uri, err := url.Parse("http://www.google.com/")
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
        var tlsConfig *tls.Config
        tlsConfig = &tls.Config{
                ServerName:         hostname,
                InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        }

        client := &http.Client{
                Transport: &http.Transport{
                        DisableKeepAlives: true,
                        TLSClientConfig:   tlsConfig,
                },
        }
        request1 := &http.Request{
                Header: http.Header{"User-Agent": {"Foo"}},
                Host:   hostname,
                Method: "GET",
                URL:    uri,
        }
        request2 := &http.Request{
                Header: http.Header{"User-Agent": {"Foo"}},
                Host:   hostname,
                Method: "GET",
                URL:    uri,
        }

        fmt.Printf("Address1: %s, Address2: %s\n", &request1.URL.Host, &request2.URL.Host)
        resp, err := client.Do(request1)
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        fmt.Printf("\nResponse: %s", resp)
}
```

Comment: You're assigning them the same value, why would they be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`http.Request`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) is a struct, whose `URL` field is a **pointer**:

```
URL *url.URL
```

In your code you have a single `uri` variable holding a pointer of type `*url.URL`.

Then you create 2 requests, storing the pointers in `request1` and `request2` variables, but you assign the same value, the same pointer to their `URL` field.

So there is a single [`url.URL`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL) value, and you assign its address to both `request1.URL` and `request2.URL`. Then you print the addresses of `request1.URL.Host` and `request2.URL.Host`, but since both `request1.URL` and `request2.URL` point to the same and only `url.URL` (struct) value, the address of the `Host` field of that struct will be the same. There are no distinct `url.URL` values for the 2 request structs.

Comment: Even if it wasn't a pointer, assigning the same value to properties of two structs will yield the same value in both structs.

Comment: Yes, it is true. They would have their own value, and the values would be the same (equal).

Comment: @icza You're right. It's been a really long day. /facepalm. Thanks

Comment: @icza, what @Adrian is pointing out is that pointers are variables just like anything else.  If you assign `42` to two ints, they have distinct and separate locations in memory, but hold the same value.  If you assign the same address to two pointers, the pointers themselves have distinct and separate locations in memory, but still hold the same value (it's just an address this time instead of an integer).